# getting long press keyboard pressed listener in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I want to make program so that until a key is pressed it does a specific event repeatedly and when it's released it don't do anything 
I am not able to achieve the same, I used pynput and keyboard library but don't know how to get this done please help

Comment: Please show how you've tried to implement this and explain what specific issues you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you have to download pynput in order to use it.

**on_press function works as you hold the any key**
**on_release key works when you release the key**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    a=5
    b=3
    print(a+b)

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```